# Tensorflow Model PreProcess Time Data

Tags: tensorflow, keras, data-preprocessing

I got information where and when a cab customer entered his vehicle. Now I want to predict in which street he wants to drive. My dataset is looking like this:

#### Example

Day, Hour, Minute, Entrance, Destination (Label)

Monday, 10, 45, ExampleStreet, StackOverflowCorner (Not PreProcessed)

0, 10, 45, 0, 1 (PreProcessed)

#### Converted like this:

Now I PreProcessed my Dataset like this:

Day -> Number from 0-6 (0 Monday, 1 Tuesday ...)

Hour -> European format from 0-24

Minute -> No preprocess

Entrance -> I used LabelEncoder (0 ExampleStreet, 1 ExampleCorner ...)

Destination -> Same like Entrance with Label Encoder

I got 98 possible destinations and the same amount of entrances and around 700 samples.
I already used Tensorflow but only get a validation accuracy near 0.

```
model = keras.Sequential([     

tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'),
keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.4),

tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'),

tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),

tf.keras.layers.Dense(98,activation="softmax")
]) 
optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop()
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy,     metrics=['accuracy'])
```

#### Questions

Did I PreProcess my data rightly? Do I need hot-encoding or gather more samples? Is another algorithm mabye more effective (Tree?)?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need one hot encoding of Entrance and day. And potentially - hour.

You need more samples (number of samples should be close to the order of a number of variables for your model). But try with one-hot and see

Comment: Thanks bro. Now my Accuracy is ~0.14 (random Acc ~ 0.01) but I am Overfitting really quick. You got an idea how I could change my model? Or do I just need collecting more data?

Comment: @MareSeestern Add regularization to your dense layers, eg by doing: `tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.001),` The regularization parameter could be varied from 0 to 0.1, where a higher number is more regularization.

Comment: @MareSeestern what is a number of trainable variables (printout of `model.summary()`) ?

Comment: @Andrey 25.000 trainable Params - So I need also 25.000 samples?

Comment: @Marcus Thanks for the hint. It did not change something :/

Comment: @MareSeestern yes. 700 is probably not enough. Try Adam though. And play with learning rate

Comment: Thanks, dude. Btw is 700 samples are random upsampled! So I only got 150 unique samples. I think there is no sense with machine learning. Will Decisions Tree more effective?

Comment: Thanks. I will try it

Comment: @MareSeestern don't forget to accept the answer if you are happy

Comment: Sure. I will wait one more day because my initial problem is not solved. But it was a nice hint which can help other programmers!

Answer (score 1):

As a minimum you should one-hot encode entrance and destination, Using the label encoding assigns integers to these features which will be interpreted by the model as being ordinal values that have a numerical relationship. Clearly there is no "ordering" of the entrance and destination. I would leave day encoded as you have done because there is clearly a sequential ordering of  days in a week, the same for hour and minute. I doubt minute has much use as a feature so you may want to not include it. With 98 classes and only 700 samples it is doubtful your model will result in very high accuracy.

Comment: Thanks Gerry, I one-hot encoded entrance, destination, (day, hour) but the low accuracy did not change.

Comment: @Gerry P it doesn't make sense to encode destination (labels) when using `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`

Comment: Also tried changing loss to categorical_crossentropy for encoding.

Comment: Oups you are correct- should not try to answer questions before first cup of coffee!